# Currying in YUI3 library

Tags: javascript, currying, yui3

Does YUI3 library have currying functionality ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currying is done using the [bind method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI~oop.html#method_bind) provided by the oop module.

```
var add3 = Y.bind(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, null, 3);
console.log(add3(39)); // prints 42
```

Comment: Thanks, Y.bind seems to be the way to go. I have my own implementation, but using this is definitely better.